# Can a Swift subscript implementation set a tuple value?

Tags: swift

My Swift class is implementing a protocol that includes the following (required) subscript:

```
subscript(index: Int) -> (Foo, Bar)? { get set }
```

This should allow me to call, for example:

```
let (foo, bar) = myObject[3]
```

and

```
myObject[3] = (foo, bar)
```

Implementing the getter is easy:

```
subscript(index: Int) -> (Foo, Bar)? {
    get {
        // Return a tuple of the values at index in the Foos and Bars arrays.
        do {
            try return (Foos[index], Bars[index])
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

However, implementing a setter seems impossible because there's no way to get at the the auto-generated `newValue`'s "members", if `newValue` is a tuple.

```
    set(newValue) {
        Foos[index] = newValue.foo    // No can do.
        Bars[index] = newValue.bar    // No can do.
    }
```

I tried force-casting `newValue` to the tuple type, like so:

```
    set(newValue) {
        if let (track, trackNumber) = newValue as! (SongVersion, TrackNumber) { ... }
    }
```

but the compiler complains that `newValue` isn't an `Optional`, so it can't be cast.

It seems to me that if this kind of subscript is unsettable, then the compiler should complain when you try to overload `subscript` to return a tuple. And I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a subscript method can have a tuple type.

First, you have defined the `subscript` value as an *optional*
`(Foo, Bar)?`, so `newValue` needs to be unwrapped. (And you have to
decide what to do if `newValue` is `nil`.)

Second, if you want
to access the tuple member by names `.foo/.bar`, you have to define a named tuple:

```
subscript(index: Int) -> (foo: Foo, bar: Bar)? {
    // ...

    set(newValue) {
        if let value = newValue {
            foos[index] = value.foo
            bars[index] = value.bar
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, access the tuple members with `value.0` and `value.1`.

Comment: Thank you! I tried naming the tuple's arguments, but I was then accessing them as-is, not as named members of newValue. I also tried using 0 and 1, but I prefixed them with a dollar sign as though I were in a code block, and obviously that didn't work, either.

Comment: I just tried your implementation, and while it does compile, I now get an error that my class does not conform to the protocol, which requires type (Int) -> (Foo, Bar)? and I have non-matching type (Int) -> (foo: Foo, bar: Bar)?  Now I'll try your second suggestion.

Comment: Ok, now this is weird. Using .0 and .1 on the newValue complains that the types don't conform because they're treated like Strings. However, if I add the tuple argument la s in the *protocol*'s definition, then the first approach works.

Comment: @NRitH: The type required in the protocol and the return type from the subscript method must be identical, both `(Foo, Bar)` or both `(foo:Foo, bar:Bar)`. Accessing the tuple members with `.0`, `.1` works in either case, but `.foo`, `.bar` only in the second case.